# Drawing a Neon/Glow line using BlurMaskFilter

Tags: java, android, android-custom-view

I'm trying to draw a Neon or Glow line like this :

[image]

the code below works fine only if the background color is white

```
 public MaskFilter setNeonBrush(float radius) {
        return new BlurMaskFilter(raduis, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.OUTER);
 }
```

**Output:**

White color as background :

[image]

Image as background :

[image]

How can I draw a neon line on bitmap as the picture attached?

Comment: What's the problem, exactly? Do you mean that you expect the line to be opaque in the last image?

Comment: @MikeM. Hi, Thank you for your comment, yes,I want to be able to draw like the 2nd picture

Comment: I'm still not quite sure what you mean, but maybe you want `BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL` instead?